# Can we use the value of localStorage from other domains?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am storing a value in local storage in one domain. Can I retrieve that value from another domain if I am accessing both domain from same browser?

Comment: No, you cannot access the local storage across domain, same as cookie.

Comment: Though you can write deliberately weak code, so you can get (actually steal) from the first domain. Have a look at this cheat sheet [Here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Local_Storage). Which I think would be a big security loophole in your application.

Comment: To load localStorage values from another domain via a link, I would pass them as [search parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) in the URL.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't use the local storage of one domain to other domain.
Local Storage is domain based. You can’t read or write from localstorage that’s on different domain even on it's subdomain.
you can use it via Iframe on your subdomain.
Please go through this article [Cross-Domain LocalStorage](https://jcubic.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/cross-domain-localstorage/) for detailed explanation.

Hope it'll help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use this javascript library.
[Bifrost-cors](https://github.com/spurushottam13/bifrost-cors)  size: <2KB

It's very simple to use, you just need to invoke method.

```
// In www.exampleA.com site:
var bifrostCors = new bifrostCors("http://exampleB.com/", false)

// In www.exampleB.com site
var bifrostCors = new bifrostCors("http://exampleA.com/", false)
bifrostCors.getLocalStorage("local-storage-key-of-what-you-want")
```

Actually this lib render the iframe (hidden) and uses window.postMessage to communicate with two different contexts (domain).
You can also implement by yourself but this lib is very very light < 2Kb.
Also not only you can access localStorage you have feature also like.

1. Get/Set Cookie
2. Bi-directional message thread
3. Run JS expression from one domain to other
4. DOM Manipulation from one domain to other domain ( Iframe )

Comment: Hi I am trying to use this but I got this error `core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: bifrostCors is not a constructor' . Do you have any idea about this

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this [blog post](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/). It seem to suggest that you can attempt to use an iframe as a workaround to access local storage from another domain.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it before but it seems interesting. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable on SO for the reason that we see here. The link is dead.