# How to remove localStorage for a domain inside an iframe with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, gecko

I tried to search but couldn't find a solution for it.

How to remove localStorage from a domain that is under an iframe with JavaScript

[image: Iframe content]

Of course I used the following action:

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

But it does not work for the iframe (here Google recaptcha). All the items still remain and I have to remove manually.

Thanks for your help

[image: LocalStorage remains]

**Edit :**
It should be noted that the JavaScript code is executed by myself on my pc. I am using Firefox and I was able to browse and delete cookies from other domains with the header:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
```

And now my question is how to have the same result with the localStorage

Comment: You mean for your own use only? If so, in the "Stockage" panel, you should be able to right click the `https://www.google.com` option in the left panel (the one highlighted in your second screenshot) and then you should have something like "Supprimer tout" ("Delete All" in English version) And if you meant from your webpage, then [that question has already been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419315/can-we-use-the-value-of-localstorage-from-other-domain).

Comment: Yes this is for my own use. I edited the topic. Ok, i can delete it manually. Now I'm looking to do it with javascript

Comment: So from your own page? Otherwise, you can still do this from the dev-tools console by first selecting the iframe's realm from the menu available at the top left of the dev-tools and then typing `localStorage.clear()`, but it's not really simpler than through Storage. Otherwise, would a browser extension / userscript be a possible solution for you?

Comment: With cookies, this worked :
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm"); 
var all_cookies = Services.cookies;

But not with LocalStorage

Comment: If for personal use, you can try Tampermonkey browser extension or any alike, specifying the domain in it..

Comment: Ok, I can use Tampermonkey or Greasemonkey or any. But the question is what line of javascript to use. Because window.localStorage.clear(); doesn't do the trick