# How can I get "token" from this localStorage item in Cypress?

Tags: local-storage, cypress

Here my localStorage
[image: Here my localStorage]
[2 localstorage displays while test runnig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSgAB.png)

I shared the localStorage's SS.

I need to use `"token"` from `"test_auth"` in Cypress and tried this:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('test_auth.token')
```

But it didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: Since you are getting an undefined error from `localStorage.getItem('test_auth')` I'd suggest you might be reading it too early in the test. Please post more info.

Comment: Actually I can see the item while test running, but there are 2 localstorage appears. Could it be problem and can we select the needed one? @fody

Comment: The two entries you are seeing refer to the "domain" which corresponds to the current domain of the web page `http://....com`.  `localStorage.getItem(...)` can only read from the current domain, but the token is arriving in the other domain. If you show the test, can probably suggest how to get around the problem.

Comment: Here's a question that illustrates the problem better [Can we use the value of localStorage from other domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419315/can-we-use-the-value-of-localstorage-from-other-domain)

Comment: Thank you for your help @fody but other suggestions also didn't work. I will search more.

Answer (score 1):

local storage stores strings so you should first parse what you get to JSON and then get what you want. below code can be your answer:

```
const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('test_auth')).token
```

Comment: It says `"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'token')"`

Comment: Are you sure test_auth still exists in your local storage with the exact same name?

Comment: const testauth = localStorage.getItem("test_auth"); const test_token = JSON.parse(testauth).token, If it doesn't work try adding window.localStorage.getItem

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a storage item with the name `'test_auth.token'`

You want to get the storage object then access it's `.token` property

```js
const token = localStorage.getItem('test_auth').token
```

Comment: It says `"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'token')"` @Fody